# Executing query from SSDT

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

I'm using Visual Studio 2015, SSIS to run set of sql tasks in Execute Sql task and then do a data transfer between tables which are in SSMS by executing package in SSIS. When we run a series of sql statements on SSMS, we get results like rows effected for every sql successful activity. However, now I want to automate the process using SSIS to reduce the turn around time. I would like to get the rows effected for every sql query like select, insert, delete which are in execute sql task. How can it be done in SSIS? I don't have dbo_owner permission to stored procedures in SSMS. I'm thinking SSIS would be a quick way. But it is very important for me to make a log of rows effected to validate the data, as it is financial data. I have nearly 10 sql statements in each sql task like select and delete. But the output is only one table.
                                                                               For example my sql task is like below

```
select * from dbo.table1;
select * from dbo.table2 where city = 'Chicago';
create dbo.table3(id int, name varchar(50);
insert into dbo.table3(1,'a');
select * from dbo.table3;
```

If I execute this in SSMS I get rows effected for each select statement and also table is created. If I execute the same through package in SSIS, how will get messages for each of them?

Comment: Please post some sample code to help illustrate your problem, thanks

Comment: I added example code. Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

I assume your data lies on SQL Server. With selects, you could use data flow tasks and row counts instead of Excecute Sql's.

For inserts and updates there's a few ways to get affected rowcount, like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1834264/5605866

or like this: http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.fi/2011/03/rowcount-for-execute-sql-statement.html

Basically the same thing but with a bit different syntax.

Comment: How can I use output clause for select statement?

Comment: Output is not available for select-statements in SQL Server. You can use Data Flow task and Row Count component for selects, as described by xChaax below.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Row Count transaformation` after the Data source and save it the variable. Can refer to this [get the number of rows returned from the Source that SHOULD be processed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14591985/in-ssis-how-do-i-get-the-number-of-rows-returned-from-the-source-that-should-be).

Hope this help.